# intellij diff result are weird after applying patch

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, newline, patch

I applied patch with subversion in IntelliJ 12.1.6(Widows7, 32bit, jdk1.6).

Below image is diff result of some file of "apply patch" dialog.
As you can see, the end of line of a file is different.
But I do not modify the end of both files.
(all files from "apply patch" are same happening)

It's a bug? or some setting problem? or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Base version (left) has `};` at last line. Your version (right) has it before last line => the lines with `};` are really different, because line at right has hidden character `\n` ([line separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) at the end.

(They are `"\n"` (Linux and MacOS X), `"\r"` (MacOS 9 and older) and `"\r\n"` (Windows).)

It's not a bug.

Comment: Hi Danix, I do not modify the end of file in working copy or in the patch but after applying patch, IntelliJ appends \r\n at the end of file. this is my problem.

Comment: Sure! Sorry for my inattention. It looks like bug. Unfortunatelly, I can't find the solution.